# Create and access custom PHP function from jQuery post in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom js file that runs in the head of my Wordpress installation successfully. I need to run an jQuery post request from this file to a PHP file so I can return a value from the database.

1. Where do I create the PHP function? I have used the functions.php file to add the custom js file to start with, but I don't want this new function to run every page load, just when requested.
2. Once I've created the PHP function wherever, how do I access it through the JQuery post request? I'm used to using local paths but Wordpress screws all that up!

I'm finding my feet in Wordpress. I am a reasonably capable developer normally in codeIgniter etc but Wordpress just seems to make everything so obscure and overly complicated! Any help appreciated!

EDIT -------------

I have now created a custom functions file in the plugins folder as per [this article)](http://wphidedash.org/2011/04/best-practice-for-adding-custom-functions/) so now I need to know how to access a function within this file from the js file in the header!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to use jQuery to do a HTTP POST request back to your WordPress app when some event happens in the browser. This is a technique known as AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML). Javascript in your browser communicates with a server without refreshing the page and can do more logic you want (in Javascript/jQuery) based on the response from the server. The server can response with more than just XML these days (JSON is pretty popular).

[AJAX in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX): Standard XML response

[AJAX in WordPress Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins): Response using jQuery. You can do this in a theme instead of a plugin. This is probably what you are looking for.

Edit: A [straightforward AJAX example](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/) using jQuery and WordPress.

Comment: Not quite... The js file loaded in the header needs to do the ajax call to a PHP function in a plugin, which will then return a value.

Comment: I promise that is what you are looking for. You cannot call PHP functions using Javascript directly. You have to pass data through requests and responses instead.

Comment: HOORAY! I don't know why Wordpress Codex explains everything in such a complicated way but I looked around, based on what you said, and found [this beautifully simple example](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/) and then, when I got an 'ajaxurl undefined' error, applied [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajaxurl-is-not-defined) and it's all working! BOOM! Thank you :)

Comment: Great! That is definitely a straightforward example as compared to what I pointed to. I will update my answer accordingly. Please don't forget to upvote. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a extension or a 3rd party wordpress analyzer  to use this.